# I can't use my usb to hdmi adapter in ubuntu 22.04 (534d:6021 MacroSilicon VGA Display Adapter)

Tags: drivers, usb, multiple-monitors, hdmi, vga

I have 534d:6021 MacroSilicon VGA Display Adapter which I want to connect my third screen through my usb 3 port. However it has only windows drivers. How can I setup this adapter with a suitable driver on my ubuntu 22.04.

```
USB 534d:6021 »
/ 03-00-00  MacroSilicon    VGA Display Adapter cdrom   uas, usb_storage    detected ￼
```

this is the output of hw-probe.

Comment: Some driver exists in source form
https://github.com/rhgndf/ms912x

Comment: how do I install that?

Comment: it says insmod: ERROR: could not load module ms912x.ko: No such file or directory

Comment: @RA How does one use this driver? Do I copy it somewhere? compile it using...? thanks

Comment: @Max there's a file insmod.sh with commands. I guess the kernel should be <6

Comment: @Max added full guide

Answer (score 2):

(I don't own the hardware so not completely tested)

1. Update to the latest Ubuntu 22.04.3 (you should be running 6.2 kernel)
2. Run these commands:

```
cd Downloads
wget https://github.com/nunesbns/ms912x/archive/refs/heads/kernel-6-support.zip
unzip kernel-6-support.zip
cd ms912x-kernel-6-support/
sudo apt install -y build-essential
make clean
make all -j
sudo modprobe drm_shmem_helper
sudo insmod ms912x.ko
journalctl -k | grep ms912x
# expected output:
# Oct 12 12:59:56 hp-laptop kernel: usbcore: registered new interface driver ms912x
```

3. Test if your device works.

Comment: it resulteds in Skipping BTF generation for /home/c/Downloads/ms912x-kernel-6-support/ms912x.ko due to unavailability of vmlinux
        and then got fixed with     https://askubuntu.com/questions/1348250/skipping-btf-generation-xxx-due-to-unavailability-of-vmlinux-on-ubuntu-21-04

Comment: make results in `make[1]: *** /lib/modules/6.1.0-11-amd64/build: No such file or directory.  Stop.`  After installing linux headers, it works with `make CHECK="/usr/bin/sparse" -C /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-11-amd64/ M=$PWD modules`

Comment: This error is occurring: `Fatal error: Invalid --compress-debug-sections option: 'zstd'`. Any idea? 

Comment: @Ale How were you able to use Kernel 6.1.0-11 if it doesn't have `drm/drm_fbdev_generic.h`? 

Comment: @RA The device is recognized, but the screen is completely dark. If I restart OS, then the driver no longer works. I have to reinstall. Any ideas about what could be going on?

Comment: @EduardoLucio https://github.com/rhgndf/ms912x you can create an issue here and ask. On reboot `sudo insmod ms912x.ko` should be enough. Also, see if there's anything strange in your journal

Comment: @RA `insmod: ERROR: could not load module ms912x.ko: No such file or directory` 

Comment: @Eduardo Lucio Just comment out the line that includes it.  Besides the link pointed by Max, also need `sudo ln -n  -s /boot/System.map-6.1.0-11-amd64 /usr/src/linux-headers-6.1.0-11-amd64/System.map` and then make the `modules_install` target.  The moduke ten loads automatically.  Yet, `xrandr` won't see it.

Comment: @Ale I didn't quite understand what you explained... Anyway, the *System.map* file doesn't exist on my system. 

Comment: I opened another topic to address issues about the **ms912x driver** - Device 534d:6021 (USB 3.0 to HDMI Adapter) - here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/759400/61742 . 

Answer (score 0):

## Install MacroSilicon USB to HDMI Adapter driver (534d:6021)

### Installation process

To install, run these commands...

```
git clone https://github.com/rhgndf/ms912x.git
cd "./ms912x"

# These git commands allow you to clean up a previous installation and ensure you
# have the latest version in case of reinstallations or tests.
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/main
git clean -fdx

make clean
make all -j
sudo rmmod ms912x # It will not work if the device is in use.
sudo insmod ms912x.ko
sudo modprobe drm_shmem_helper
```

**IMPORTANT:** Linux kernel 6.2.X (or above) is necessary, because of DRM support.

**EXTRA:** Necessary packages for Manjaro Linux `yay -S linux65; yay -S linux65-headers; yay -S make; yay -S base-devel; yay -S binutils; yay -S libdrm; yay -S sparse; yay -S zstd`. Ubuntu has equivalent packages (Kernel's ones, perhaps not).

... OR (simply)...

```
bash insmod.sh
```

### Information about your device (or about problems with it)

Some commands to obtain information about your device (or about problems with it)...

```
lsusb -v
dmesg | grep -Ei "ms912x"
journalctl -k | grep -Ei "ms912x"
edid-decode < /sys/class/drm/<YOUR_DEVICE>/edid
cat /etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/10-prime-offload.conf
```

### Results I got

On Linux, the performance is **UNACCEPTABLE** and there are also compatibility problems.

Other than that the device claims to be USB 3.0, but it's just USB 2.0 .

**NOTE:** It [didn't work with the KDE gui using X11](https://github.com/rhgndf/ms912x/issues/6) (I had to use Wayland that is immature). The distribution tested was Manjaro KDE.

### Conclusion

Unfortunately, MacroSilicon is not interested in Linux users (a shame, really ), nor does it support important and valuable open source projects like this one [ms912x driver for Linux](https://github.com/rhgndf/ms912x).

Therefore, at the moment, **my** guidance is that Linux users use devices based on DisplayLink chips (manufacturer Synaptics). I tested the *WL-UG3501H* device, for example, and had excellent results. The manufacturer Synaptics provides good support for Linux drivers.

**EXTRA:** To install drivers for devices based on DisplayLink chips (manufacturer Synaptics) on Manjaro Linux use the command `yay -S displaylink`. Ubuntu has an equivalent package.

**PLUS:** [USB video card adapters for Linux Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/a/1486986/134723) .

**Thanks!**